# Select Query Optimization

Tags: c#, mysql, query-optimization, ibatis

I have select query that fetch record based on a condition

```
Select * from Employee where EmpStatus=#EmpStatus#
```

The EmpStatus in the DB for each employee would either 0 or 1.

```
EmpID EmpName EmpStatus
***********************
1     Name1   0
2     Name2   0
3     Name4   1
4     Name5   1
```

When I pass EmpStatus as 1, I should get list containing ONLY 3 and 4. But if i pass EmpStatus as 0, ALL the 4 records should be fetched. How can this be done with a single optimal select query?

Comment: For fetching four rows there shouldn't be a performance issue. I suspect that you're missing out some important details which are necessary to know to optimize the performance. For example, how many rows are there, how many rows with EmpStatus 0 and how many with 1? Are you querying an entire table or the result of another query? Are there any other columns involved in your query that you are omitting in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change = to >=:

```
SELECT col1, col2 -- etc...
FROM Employee
WHERE EmpStatus >= #EmpStatus#
```

The most important thing for performance is to add an appropriate index.

Comment: Good answer. One other thing that I think is important is to avoid "SELECT *". 

It can be bad to select everything if your code is going to change because ibatis will not be able to map your new fields until you have the same field in your resultmap object. This can cause runtime errors that are difficult to track down ("my code didn't change but the program now crashes!" after adding a database column).